# Is it possible to create a volume with 'Microsoft SQL Server' docker container?

Tags: sql-server, docker

I run the following command on my linux machine, and want to attach a volume, like in Mysql

```sh
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=12345678' -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can attach a volume on the Microsoft SQL Server too, as [described on the Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-docker?view=sql-server-ver15#persist):

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=12345678' -p 1433:1433 -v <host directory>/data:/var/opt/mssql/data -v <host directory>/log:/var/opt/mssql/log -v <host directory>/secrets:/var/opt/mssql/secrets -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

Using the above command you [mount three folders of the container to a host directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-docker?view=sql-server-ver15#mount-a-host-directory-as-data-volume):

- `<host directory>/data:/var/opt/mssql/data`
- `<host directory>/log:/var/opt/mssql/log`
- `<host directory>/secrets:/var/opt/mssql/secrets`

You can also use a [data volume container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-docker?view=sql-server-ver15#use-data-volume-containers) instead of a mounted host directory:

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=12345678' -p 1433:1433 -v sqlvolume:/var/opt/mssql -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

Comment: Thank you!  One last question, Is it possible to run this Mssql and connect it to an administration tool like phpmyadmin in Mysql?   I'm using linux server to run this image and prefer to see the tables on a browser

Comment: also on the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-docker?view=sql-server-ver15#tools-outside-the-container

Comment: The SA_PASSWORD environment variable is deprecated. Use MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD instead.

Answer (score 12):

You can use this as `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
services:
  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/opt/mssql/data
      - ./log:/var/opt/mssql/log
      - ./secrets:/var/opt/mssql/secrets
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=123456789
```

Then, to prevent permission denied error create data,log and secrets folder and change their permission:

```
mkdir data && sudo chown 10001 data
mkdir log && sudo chown 10001 log
mkdir secrets && sudo chown 10001 secrets
```

And finally, use `docker-compose up -d` to start the container.

Comment: I think you missed "data" in 1st volume mapping. It should be `./data:/var/opt/mssql/data` instead of `./data:/var/opt/mssql/`

Comment: Yes! Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

inspect the file `/var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf` and you will get the location of all data under `[filelocation]` section:

```ini
[filelocation]
#defaultbackupdir                # Default directory for backup files
#defaultdatadir                  # Default directory for data files
#defaultdumpdir                  # Default directory for crash dump files
#defaultlogdir                   # Default directory for log files
#errorlogfile                    # Error log file location
#masterdatafile                  # Master database data file location
#masterlogfile                   # Master database log file location
```